# re-shape matrix to 3D array in specific order

Tags: arrays, r, reshape

I'm attempting to reshape a 2D matrix into a 3D array in a specific order. This seems like a fairly trivial exercise but I cant seem to find the right way to do it.

```
             X          Y
 [1,] 276.9421  0.0000000
 [2,] 276.4248 -5.3750000
 [3,] 276.2253 -5.3333333
 [4,] 275.9051 -3.8125000
 [5,] 275.6589 -1.8200000
 [6,] 275.6311  0.6388889
 [7,] 275.6540  2.2142857
 [8,] 275.5883  2.9296875
 [9,] 275.7367  3.2222222
 [10,] 276.4208  3.2550000
 [11,] 277.0216  3.1528926
 [12,] 277.3477  3.0104167
 [13,] 277.3471  3.3576389
 [14,] 277.5270  4.7152778
 [15,] 277.5288  5.9027778
```

Lets take this 2x15 matrix. What I want is to reshape this into a 3D array containing 3 samples where each sample has 5 rows and 2 columns that correspond to the existing structure of this matrix. So imagine that I want to split this into a list of 3 elements where each element is a 5x2 matrix in the same order as you see in the above matrix. However I dont need a list of matrices but an array.

Output desired,

```
,,1
X          Y
[1,] 276.9421  0.0000000
[2,] 276.4248 -5.3750000
[3,] 276.2253 -5.3333333
[4,] 275.9051 -3.8125000
[5,] 275.6589 -1.8200000

,,2
X          Y
[6,] 275.6311  0.6388889
[7,] 275.6540  2.2142857
[8,] 275.5883  2.9296875
[9,] 275.7367  3.2222222
[10,] 276.4208  3.2550000

,,3
X          Y
[11,] 277.0216  3.1528926
[12,] 277.3477  3.0104167
[13,] 277.3471  3.3576389
[14,] 277.5270  4.7152778
[15,] 277.5288  5.9027778
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `array(sapply(seq(5, 15, 5), function(i) m[(i-4):i,]), dim = c(5, 2, 3))`

Comment: How about `split(df, factor(sort(rank(row.names(d))%%3)))`?

Comment: @d.b Thanks that works!

Comment: @Majo I get the following error (assuming you meant df in `row.names(d)`), `Error in split.default(df, factor(sort(rank(row.names(df))%%3))) : 
  group length is 0 but data length > 0
In addition: Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'`

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry about that. It should be `df`not `d`. I have edited the comment here: `split(df, factor(sort(rank(row.names(df))%%3)))`

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas that come to mind involve splitting the data in some form and then using `array` to get the data into the form you want.

First, here's some sample data:

```
m <- structure(c(276.9421, 276.4248, 276.2253, 275.9051, 275.6589, 
    275.6311, 275.654, 275.5883, 275.7367, 276.4208, 277.0216, 277.3477, 
    277.3471, 277.527, 277.5288, 0, -5.375, -5.3333333, -3.8125, 
    -1.82, 0.6388889, 2.2142857, 2.9296875, 3.2222222, 3.255, 3.1528926, 
    3.0104167, 3.3576389, 4.7152778, 5.9027778), .Dim = c(15L, 2L
    ), .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X", "Y")))

m
##              X          Y
##  [1,] 276.9421  0.0000000
##  [2,] 276.4248 -5.3750000
##  [3,] 276.2253 -5.3333333
##  [4,] 275.9051 -3.8125000
##  [5,] 275.6589 -1.8200000
##  [6,] 275.6311  0.6388889
##  [7,] 275.6540  2.2142857
##  [8,] 275.5883  2.9296875
##  [9,] 275.7367  3.2222222
## [10,] 276.4208  3.2550000
## [11,] 277.0216  3.1528926
## [12,] 277.3477  3.0104167
## [13,] 277.3471  3.3576389
## [14,] 277.5270  4.7152778
## [15,] 277.5288  5.9027778
```

The easiest option to think about is to convert the `matrix` to a `data.frame`, split it every 5 rows, unlist it, and put the values into an `array`:

```
array(unlist(split(data.frame(m), rep(1:3, each  = 5))), c(5, 2, 3))
```

The second option that I thought of was to split the matrix directly, which splits by column.

```
array(unlist(split(m, rep(gl(3, 5), 2)), use.names = FALSE), c(5, 2, 3))
```

Either of these can be generalised as a function that might look like this:

```
mat2_3d1 <- function(inmat, n) {
  if (nrow(inmat) %% n != 0) stop("incompatible dimensions provided")
  dims <- c(nrow(inmat) %/% n, ncol(inmat), n)
  temp <- split(data.frame(inmat), rep(sequence(n), each = dims[1]))
  array(unlist(temp, use.names = FALSE), dim = dims)
}

mat2_3d1(m, 3)
```

or this:

```
mat2_3d2 <- function(inmat, n) {
  if (nrow(inmat) %% n != 0) stop("incompatible dimensions provided")
  dims <- c(nrow(inmat) %/% n, ncol(inmat), n)
  array(unlist(split(inmat, gl(n, dims[1])), use.names = FALSE), dim = dims)
}

mat2_3d2(m, 3)
```

Both would result in:

```
mat2_3d2(m, 3)
## , , 1
## 
##          [,1]      [,2]
## [1,] 276.9421  0.000000
## [2,] 276.4248 -5.375000
## [3,] 276.2253 -5.333333
## [4,] 275.9051 -3.812500
## [5,] 275.6589 -1.820000
## 
## , , 2
## 
##          [,1]      [,2]
## [1,] 275.6311 0.6388889
## [2,] 275.6540 2.2142857
## [3,] 275.5883 2.9296875
## [4,] 275.7367 3.2222222
## [5,] 276.4208 3.2550000
## 
## , , 3
## 
##          [,1]     [,2]
## [1,] 277.0216 3.152893
## [2,] 277.3477 3.010417
## [3,] 277.3471 3.357639
## [4,] 277.5270 4.715278
## [5,] 277.5288 5.902778
##
```

I would suspect that the second option would be more efficient since it's just splitting a vector, rather than converting to a `data.frame` and then splitting.